# Python optimisation algorithm related to piecewise functions

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization

I have a type of piecewise functions f(p,q,x) which is determined by the lists q and p.
For example, the following means f is 100 when x is between [0,3] and is 95 when x is between (3,5].
    p     q
    100   3
    95    2
    90    6

My problem is to find the largest x that satisfies f(pa,qa,x) < p(pb,qb,x), given the parameters pa, qa, pb, qb (pa is sorted in asending order and pb is sorted in descending order).

I could think of a naïve solution like below.

```
def f(p,q,x):
  y=0
  for i in range(len(p)):
   y+=q[i]
   if y>=x:
       return p[i]
return p[len(p)-1]

pa=[92,94,104]
qa=[4,2,3]
pb=[100,95,90]
qb=[3,2,6]

x=0
for i in range(min(sum(qa),sum(qb))):
    if f(pa,qa,i)<f(pb,qb,i):
        x=i
    else:
        break
print(x)
```

But this solution has two issues.
* it does not work with float input
* it is inefficient and may have performance issues when the lists are big
Could anyone point me to an elegant solution which avoids the above issues?

By the way, I know this can be solved easily in pulp or scipy linprog but would prefer to use an specialised algorithm instead.

Thanks a lot,

Acquila

Comment: Since the two functions have different steps, you probably can't use range. You need to look at qa/qb to determine the next x, and only evaluate distinct values. No sense doing f(x+1) when you know neither function changes over that range. And because you want the largest x, you may want to start from the high end and work back.

Comment: The problem with floats is you need to give an integer to the range function. The quick fix for that is just int() or math.ceil(). Then your solution works as long as fa is increasing and fb is decreasing. But I think it is incorrect for arbitrary input, but you said you sort them to enforce that condition, so no problem. That means you can also do a binary search within the range, although that may be slower unless you build a lookup table for the steps.

Comment: (and building the lookup table is probably the same work as actually solving the whole problem)

Comment: Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Indeed there is room for improvement in the part for i in range(min(sum(qa),sum(qb))). And also the way f(p,q,x) is written (it counts from the first item every time). So I have tried to combine the two into  one loop (using indices for a and b).

This improves the performance but makes the code more lengthy and less comprehensible. And I now I am looking for something which is both performant and elegant.